Problem on parallel transport and covariant derivative
Problem goes as follows:
From the definition of the covariant derivative, prove that
$$ \tilde{V}^{\mu}(x^{\alpha} + \Delta x^{\alpha}) = V^{\mu}(x^{\alpha})-V^{\lambda}(x^{\alpha}) \Gamma^{\mu}_{\lambda \nu} \Delta x^{\nu} + O((\Delta x^{\alpha})^{2})$$
where $\tilde{V}^{\mu}(x^{\alpha} + \Delta x^{\alpha})$ is the parallel transport of
$V^{\mu}(x^{\alpha})$ on the point $x^{\alpha}+ \Delta x^{\alpha}$.
I have not found any problem similar to this anywhere, so I could really use some guidance here.
I guessing the definition of covariant derivative that can help me the most is
$$ \nabla_{\mu} V^{\nu} = \partial_{\mu} V^{\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu \lambda} V^{\lambda}$$, but Iḿ confused on how to apply it.

This makes no sense to me as it stands. So $P=(x^\alpha)$ (an $n$-tuple with $\alpha$ varying from $1$ to $n$), and $Q=(x^\alpha+\Delta x^\alpha)$ is a nearby point. To talk about parallel transport of a vector, we need a specific path. The parallel transport will be different with different paths, but the difference will be quadratic, so maybe this is OK. The intuition is that if the vector field is rotating as we move along the path, then to get a parallel vector field we must rotate precisely the opposite amount to compensate.

At any rate, think of your displayed equation for $\nabla_\mu \tilde V{}^\nu = 0$ and then do a first-order Taylor expansion.
